# Using Selenium webdriver Java to locate elements with unclear Id's classes

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

Hi I need to know how to locate an element that has no ID or name, and is located within classes, without using xPath for Webdriver

How can I locate the link in the image below without using xPath, using webdriver.

I've included an image:

[image]

Comment: Hi, Welcome to StackOverflow. It would be a good idea to host that image somewhere else, or embed it into the question (preferred). The site you are using is blocked on my corporate network, so may be in others too.

Comment: @Serdalis Low-rep users can't post pictures directly.

Comment: @tbodt Thanks didn't know that, The re hosting part is definitely relevant, since I can't view the image.

Comment: I replaced the image link with the actual image. (Try to avoid using tinypic in the future. It looks like a pile of ads and spam to me.)

Comment: @Serdalis When I opened that link, it was a page that offered to show me the image. I clicked on the image, and a popup offered to install some malware. That must be why it's blocked.

Comment: Sorry I had a low rep I couldn't post an image, I'll try google drive next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it this is what I got and it worked

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".links > a[ng-click*=Photos]"));

Answer (score 1):

This CSS selector should work, you can use By.CssSelector:

```
.links > a[ng-click*="Photos"]
```

Comment: It doesn't accept it this way, This is what I have: driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(.links > a[ng-click*="Photos"]));

Comment: Needed to put the "" around the whole thing

Answer (score 0):

You can use css selectors to select this link by attributes for example by ng-click, data-target, and href attributes

```
div.links > a[ng-click="loadModal('Photos')" data-target="#myModal" href="#"]
```

References and tutorials:

1. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp
2. http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/attribute-selector-css-selector/

Comment: Hi Ahmed, sorry forgot to mention I need to do this in selenium webdriver. How would I use that? getElement.By ...

Comment: I know to use this driver.findElement(By.cssSelector() I just don't know how to input that properly into the command. thanks